# How to allow an app and widget to "share" methods

Tags: android, service, widget

I am programming a fartbutton app and widget. The widget should use the exact same methods to play the fart sounds.

In the **main app** the following method gets called in the MainActivity.java's *onCreate()*:

```
public void initializeSoundPool() {
    // Initialize SoundPool:
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    String[] soundArray = new String[1];

    // Saving all sounds' names:
    try {
        soundArray = this.getAssets().list("fartSounds");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Loading all sounds into SoundPool:
    soundCount = soundArray.length;
    soundCollection = new int[soundCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < soundCount; i++) {
        try {
            soundCollection[i] = soundPool.load(this.getAssets().openFd("fartSounds/" + soundArray[i]), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When the user presses the (only) ImageButton, its onClick-method **fart()** inside the MainActivity gets called:

```
public void fart(View view) {
    // Randomize sample and frequency:
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(soundCount);
    while (randomNumber == lastPlayed) {
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(soundCount);
    }
    int currentSound = soundCollection[randomNumber];
    float frq = random.nextFloat() + 1f;

    // Play selected sound with selected frequency:
    soundPool.play(currentSound, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, frq);

    // Save the sound's number for next time a sound should play:
    lastPlayed = randomNumber;
}
```

For the **widget** I finally figured out a way to act upon clicking:

```
public class FurzknopfWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "fart";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, FurzknopfWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FurzknopfWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_CLICK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetFartButton, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CLICK)) {
            Log.d("Widget", "FART!");
        }
    }
}
```

Since the widget basically is exactly like the app, I'd like to use the same soundpool and the same sounds. I later might want to add the option to record own sounds, so the solution should try to enable changes to settings made in the (future) app to directly affect the widget.

I have a few questions in this regard:

- How do I access the app's methods from the widget's code (since I don't know how to make a *non-static* call)?
- Would a service that runs the whole time in the background and is shared by both the app and the widget be a good idea? (Because of memory and energy concerns?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use a `Service` to manage all music operations(playback, initialization, etc) & handle all communication through Intents.

There's an [AOSP project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/src/com/example/android/musicplayer) showing that(MusicService class)

Comment: I know, in my case this is not really important, but having a `service` running in the background "eats up" resources, doesn't it? Since I technically only need to play a few short sounds, is there maybe a more "resource efficient" way to only start a service when the button is clicked and kill it after a few seconds?

Comment: Just implement service that way it doesn't eat spare resources and stops itself when needed. You won't notice such a 'huge' resource usage lol